# What are some of the best textbooks on multi-objective optimization?

Tags: reference-request, optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I am looking for textbooks on non-linear multi-objective optimization that are rigorous. For instance, I am most comfortable with Arkadi Nemirovski style. I am looking for a book on nonlinear multi-objective optimization that is close in style to Nemirovski's style

Comment: yes there are many books on the topic but not written in style of Arkadi Nemirovski or Nocedal's.

Comment: The famous ones are by Boyd and Vandenberghe and by Bertsekas, Nedic, Ozdaglar.  Here is a (self-promoting) link to a recent book chapter on a specific topic in that area (dual subrgradient algorithm and a recent faster one of similar Lagrangian-based type...the link has the full proofs and also some exercises): http://ee.usc.edu/stochastic-nets/docs/convexity-chapter-fast-convex-programming.pdf

Comment: None of the references mentioned by @Michael deal with multi-objective optimization...

Comment: @BrianBorchers : I'm not sure the goals of your comment; it is also an unusual comment. In multi-objective optimization one often wants to choose a vector $x \in X$ to make several functions $f(x), g_1(x), g_2(x), ..., g_k(x)$ small.  Well it is generally impossible to minimize all of them simultaneously, so an important approach is to minimize one subject to constraints on the other, called a "constrained optimization problem."  The references I gave do focus on cases when such problems are convex, although this is an important scenario, and nonconvexities can sometimes be treated similarly.